# You cannot upload content to files of type application/vnd.google-apps.folder

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I want to add new folder in google drive
I use this code:

```
   Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
   body.Title = "title";
   body.Description = "description";
   body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

   byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
   System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
   Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request =         
                                   service.Files.Insert(body, stream, mimeType);
   Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File parentFolder = request.Upload();
```

in line with code :
`request.Upload()` I receive this error:**You cannot upload content to files of type application/vnd.google-apps.folder**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request =         
                               service.Files.Insert(body, stream, mimeType);
```

You should do a simple Insert. By calling InsertMediaUpload you are telling drive that you are attempting to upload some content into the Folder entity, which of course makes no sense.